# Excluding accents from the vue filter, using bootstrap-vue table filter feature

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm using [Bootrap-vue Table and filtering results](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table) and I need help to insert a regex filter to exclude words/letters with accents.

This one is regex snippet:

```
string.replace('/[áàãâä]/ui', 'a');
string.replace('/[éèêë]/ui', 'e');
string.replace('/[íìîï]/ui', 'i');
string.replace('/[óòõôö]/ui', 'o');
string.replace('/[úùûü]/ui', 'u');
string.replace('/[ç]/ui', 'c');
```

Input to get user typing:

```
              <b-form-input
                id="filter-input"
                v-model="filter"
                type="search"
                placeholder="Pesquise por Zona, WhatsApp ou E-mail"
              ></b-form-input
```

Table:

```
<b-table :items="items"
                   :fields="fields"
                   :filter="filter"
                   hover
                   striped>
            <template #cell(whatsapp)="data">
              <span v-html="data.value"></span>
            </template>
            <template #cell(email)="data">
              <span v-html="data.value"></span>
            </template>
</b-table>
```

And finally, vue filter line:

```
filter: null,
```

So my question is: How can I fit the regex filter into the bootstrap-vue table filter, is it possible?

Comment: Are you really trying to exclude those words from the table? Or just modify them? Your regex snippet suggests the latter.

Comment: @tony19 I want to filter "a" when user type "á" or "ã", for example... just to ignore the  accents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a computed property that creates a regular expression from the `filter` property, replacing undecorated letters with the possible letter accents:

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    computedFilter() {
      const pattern = this.filter
          .replace(/a/g, '[aáàãâä]')
          .replace(/e/g, '[eéèêë]')
          .replace(/i/g, '[iíìîï]')
          .replace(/o/g, '[oóòõôö]')
          .replace(/u/g, '[uúùûü]')
          .replace(/c/g, '[cç]')
      return new RegExp(pattern, 'ui')
    }
  }
}
```

Then use the computed prop in your template:

```html
<b-table :filter="computedFilter">
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/abWMLXo?editors=1010)